# Как сделать сортировку выбором в двумерном массиве? C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Отсортированный массив:
[image: Отсортированный массив]
Как написать сортировку выбором?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void ArrayInputRandom(int** arr, int rows, int colums);

void ArrayInput(int** arr, int rows, int colums);

void ArrayOutput(int** arr, int rows, int colums);

int bubleSort(int size, int** arr);

int choosenSort(int size, int** arr);

int menuItem();

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int optionSort;
const int rows = 10;
const int colums = 10;
int** mas = new int* [rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    mas[i] = new int[colums];
int variant = menuItem();
if (variant == 1)
{
    cout << "Массив:" << endl;
    ArrayInputRandom(mas, rows, colums);
    ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
    cout << "1.Пузырьком <-\n"
        << "2.Выбором <-\n"
        << "3.Выход ->\n"
        << ">>> ";
    cin >> optionSort;
    switch (optionSort)
    {
    case 1:
        **mas = bubleSort(rows, mas);
        ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
        break;
    case 2:
        choosenSort(rows, mas);
        ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "-Выход-" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    default:
        cerr << "!неверный вариант!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
else if (variant == 2)
{
    cout << "Массив:" << endl;
    ArrayInput(mas, rows, colums);
    ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
    cout << "1.Пузырьком\n"
        << "2.Выбором\n"
        << "3.Выход\n"
        << ">>> ";
    cin >> optionSort;
    switch (optionSort)
    {
    case 1:
        **mas = bubleSort(rows, mas);
        ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
        break;
    case 2:
        **mas = choosenSort(rows, mas);
        ArrayOutput(mas, rows, colums);
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "-Выход-" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    default:
        cerr << "!неверный вариант!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
else cout << "Неверное значение, программа завершина!";

return 0;
}


// выбором
int choosenSort(int size, int** arr) {
cout << endl;
int min;
int test = 0;
int point = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
{
    for (int i = size - j - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size - 1; ++col)
            for (int row = size - col - 1; row >= 0; --row)
            {
                if (row > 0)
                {

                }
            }
        return **arr;
    }
}
}

int bubleSort(int size, int** arr) {
cout << endl;

int test = 0;
int point = 1;
for (int j = 0 ; j < size; ++j)
{
    for (int i = size - j - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size - 1; ++col)
            for (int row = size - col - 1; row >= 0; --row)
            {
                if (row > 0)
                {
                    if (arr[row][col] > arr[row - 1][col])
                        swap(arr[row][col], arr[row - 1][col]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (arr[row][col] > arr[size - 2 -  col][col+1])
                        swap(arr[row][col], arr[size - 2 - col][col + 1]);
                }
            }
    }
}
    /*
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size-1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j][test] < arr[j + 1][test])
            swap(arr[j][test], arr[j + 1][test]);
    }
    test--;
}
*/
return **arr;
}

void ArrayInputRandom(int** arr, int rows, int colums)
{
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < colums; j++)
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 101;
}
void ArrayInput(int** arr, int rows, int colums)
{
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < colums; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter:";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
void ArrayOutput(int** arr, int rows, int colums)
{
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colums; j++)
        cout << "\t" << arr[i][j];
    cout << "\n";
}
}
int menuItem()
{
int variant;
cout << "Выберите вариант\n" << endl;
cout << "1. Рандом\n"
    << "2. В ручную\n"
    << ">>> ";
cin >> variant;
return variant;
}
```

Comment: А я не понял вопроса. Почему выходные данные представлены в треугольном виде? Так кажется, что сортировка должна быть в линейном массиве, а потом выводить его в вашем треугольном виде.